# going to do vs doing - when talking about future

Tags: tense

> "I am not **coming** on your show ever again", said the artist.

vs

> "I am not **going to come** on your show ever again", said the artist.

Which form is correct? What difference will it make to the meaning of the sentence if we change **going to** to **will**?

Also

> "I am **going to become** a musician when I grow up"

vs

> "I am **becoming** a musician when I grow up"

What form do we use when we are talking about an activity that is meant to happen not just in near future, but also may happen (lets say 20 years from now) - the **going to do** form or the **doing** form? Take the above sentence for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Going** is frequently used in the sense of **willing** or **desiring**.

Thus **I'm not going to come....** is a way of saying **I'm not willing to come**.

It's a slightly less direct and less forceful way of saying **I'm not coming**.

But both are idiomatic and acceptable in most contexts and they come down to the same thing. Neither is better than the other. The choice depends on preference and circumstance.

A child might say **I'm going to become a musician**, indicating an ambition.

A student might say **I'm becoming a musician**, indicating musical progress.